# Вывод через php и проблемы с :last-child

Tags: php

```
<div class="katalog">
<p>Каталог</p>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach($products as $product): ?>
            <a href="#"><li><?=$product['name']?></li></a>
    <?php endforeach;?>
    </ul>
</div> <!-- /katalog -->
```

Для каждого елемента li задано бордеры верхний и нижний, но у первого и последнего надо убрать соответственно верхний и нижний бордер. Через :last-child и :first-child не получается почему то. Помогите кто может! Спасибо заранее!

Comment: css код добавьте

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5):

Так как подробностей и примера кода нет, то предположу, что проблема в невалидной верстке: `ul` должен содержать `li` в качестве дочерних элементов, а у вас там `a`. Поэтому `:last-child` и `:first-child` у вас применяются к каждому `li` - у них нет "братьев" на одном уровне вложенности, а потому каждый элемент списка одновременно и последний, и первый.

Можете заменить на корректную структуру, если она вам подходит:

```
<div class="сatalog">
<p>Каталог</p>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($products as $product): ?>
            <li><a href="#"><?=$product['name']?></a></li>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Либо измените селектор и выбирайте элементы `a:last-child`, `a:first-child` так как они у вас являются дочерними для `ul` и находятся на одном уровне вложенности. Но учитывайте, что ссылки могут быть где-то еще, потому селектор надо как-то конкретизировать (добавить новый `id` или `class`, например, для `ul`):

HTML:

```
<ul class="list"> 
    ... 
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul.list a:first-child
```

Comment: А если сделать так как вы посоветовали, можно ли как то сделать, что бы ссылка нажималась во всем <li>, а не только при нажимании на слово....?

Comment: @ОлегМельник  Для стиля ссылки можете попробовать добавить `display:block;`